# What is the fastest way to modify pixels in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap

I want to change the specified pixel in a bitmap to transparent.
The method is as follows：

```
        Bitmap bt = new Bitmap(Mybitmap);
        System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, Mybitmap.Width, Mybitmap.Height);
        BitmapData bmpdata = bt.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bt.PixelFormat);
        IntPtr ptr = bmpdata.Scan0;
        int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpdata.Stride) * bt.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
        int len = rgbValues.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 4)
        {
            //Some colors are already stored in this SpecificColor1ist, and pixels with the same color will be changed to transparent
            foreach (var item in SpecificColor1ist)
            {
                
                if ((rgbValues[i]==item.B)&&(rgbValues[i+1] == item.G)&&(rgbValues[i+2] == item.R))
                {
                    rgbValues[i + 3] = (byte)0;
                }
            }

        }
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);
        bt.UnlockBits(bmpdata);
        return bt;
```

But the speed is too slow. Is there any way to make it faster? Unsafe code is also acceptable.

Comment: Define "too slow". What makes you think it could be faster? How fast does it need to be? What have you tried so far to improve on the code above? Have you bothered to try adapting the above to unsafe code so that you can avoid the `Marshal.Copy()` calls?

Comment: Firstly you have a pointer to the pixel data array, why not use it `Scan0` ? Secondly you could make sure your pixel format is 32 bits so it works well with your cpu. thirdly, you could compare your `rbg` values in one go with in int (given you did the above) ,

Comment: An obvious bit of optimisation: put in a `break` when you find that colour in `SpecificColor1ist`. You're continuing to go through those colours even after you already matched one and performed the alpha-clearing operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have a pointer to the pixel data array, why not use it `Scan0` (you will need to set your method as unsafe, and set it appropriately in the build options for your project)
2. you could make sure your pixel format is 32 bits.
3. You could compare your rbg values in one go with in int
4. Use a HashSet for a faster lookup
5. Clear the apha-channel using a *bitwise* `&`

**Example**

```
var colorHash = SpecificColor1ist
   .Select(x => x.ToArgb())
   .ToHashSet();

...

var data = bt.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);


var length = (int*)data.Scan0 + Mybitmap.Height * Mybitmap.Width;
for (var p = (int*)data.Scan0; p < length; p++)
   if(colorHash .Contains(*p))
      *p = (*p & 0xFFFFFF) // i think sets the alpha to 0

...
```

Comment: @CaiusJard Yeah, i am a little uncertain i am setting the right byte here.

Comment: Maybe it's an endianness thing and they're the same difference!

Comment: @CaiusJard yeah, i think (tentatively) this is right

Comment: @MichaelRandall Thank you very much!With your code, the speed has been greatly improved, but this line of code "*p = (*p & 0xFFFFFF)" doesn't seem to work. How should I replace it with transparency?

Comment: @howze so when you say transparency, do you mean setting the alpha channel to 0 ?

Comment: @MichaelRandall Sorry，The comment above is that I made a mistake。you have solved my problem perfectly!Thanks a lot!